# Cisco 3850: Process responsible for Softbuffers

Tags: cisco, qos, ios-xe, cisco-3850

There is a command to increase the SoftMax Buffers on 3850 switches:

```
qos queue-softmax-multiplier 200
```

This is done in percent which means i am doubling the amount of softmax buffer.

Before, the SoftMax buffers for 10Gig interface are at 2000:

```
switch#sh platform hardware fed switch 2 qos queue config interface Te2/0/37
DATA Port:1 GPN:1425 AFD:Disabled QoSMap:0 HW Queues: 8 - 15
  DrainFast:Disabled PortSoftStart:3 - 4500
----------------------------------------------------------
   DTS  Hardmax  Softmax   PortSMin  GlblSMin  PortStEnd
  ----- --------  --------  --------  --------  ---------
 0   1  6   500   7  2000   7  1280   0     0   5  6000
 1   1  4     0   8  3000   8  1920   3   750   5  6000
 2   1  4     0   5     0   5     0   0     0   5  6000
 3   1  4     0   5     0   5     0   0     0   5  6000
 4   1  4     0   5     0   5     0   0     0   5  6000
 5   1  4     0   5     0   5     0   0     0   5  6000
 6   1  4     0   5     0   5     0   0     0   5  6000
 7   1  4     0   5     0   5     0   0     0   5  6000
```

After the command, they increased to 4000:

```
swRZ101#sh platform hardware fed switch 2 qos queue config interface Te2/0/37
DATA Port:1 GPN:1425 AFD:Disabled QoSMap:0 HW Queues: 8 - 15
  DrainFast:Disabled PortSoftStart:5 - 7500
----------------------------------------------------------
   DTS  Hardmax  Softmax   PortSMin  GlblSMin  PortStEnd
  ----- --------  --------  --------  --------  ---------
 0   1  6   500  12  4000   7  1280   0     0   7 10000
 1   1  4     0  13  6000   8  1920   3   750   7 10000
 2   1  4     0   5     0   5     0   0     0   7 10000
 3   1  4     0   5     0   5     0   0     0   7 10000
 4   1  4     0   5     0   5     0   0     0   7 10000
 5   1  4     0   5     0   5     0   0     0   7 10000
 6   1  4     0   5     0   5     0   0     0   7 10000
 7   1  4     0   5     0   5     0   0     0   7 10000
```

two questions arise from this:

- Are these bytes or queues or potatoes? I couldnt find anyting online.
- What about the ressources if i increase this to the max (12x) on the switch? Im guessing, these buffers are comming from the RAM. Is there a process where i can observe the memory usage not to overcommit anything? This is a stack of switches with 246 interfaces total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are these bytes or queues or potatoes? I couldnt find anyting online.

Cisco maintains documentation on its devices. For example, it took me about 30 seconds to find this by searching for `cisco 3850 softmax buffer`. I have higlighted the relavant text from *[Catalyst 3850: Troubleshooting Output drops](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-3850-series-switches/200594-Catalyst-3850-Troubleshooting-Output-dr.html)*:

> The Default Buffer allocation for a 1GB port is 300 buffers and for a
>   10GB port, it is 1800 buffers (***1 buffer = 256 bytes***).

---

> What about the ressources if i increase this to the max (12x) on the
>   switch? Im guessing, these buffers are comming from the RAM. Is there
>   a process where i can observe the memory usage not to overcommit
>   anything? This is a stack of switches with 246 interfaces total.

Cisco has many different command variations to show the memory usage, from very detailed to general. For example:

```
show memory statistics
```

will show the processor and I/O (what you want) memory statistics in a condensed format. You can use the `?` to see all the variations of the `show memory` command.

Comment: I was looking for the name of the process that is responsible for the softmax buffer to observe. But i guess just checking that the memory overall is not exhausted, is another way to go about this.